# Website lock in Ipad browser?

Tags: ipad, web, scroll, html, meta-tags

I notice that on sites such as http://twitter.com and http://www.linkedin.com, when opened in an Ipad using safari, the page's width is locked to the window so even if you try to scroll horizontally it will not budge, whereas on my site the frame will move, revealing a grey background.

Does anyone know how the pages listed above do this.

I am using the:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">
```

as the way to control some properties but have yet to discover the way to lock/prevent the page from being able to move from left to right. vertical scrolling is perfect ofcourse.

Just to clarify, the page doesnt have a horiz scroll bar as it is fixed to 1024px and is centered, never-the-less, when you use your finger and move it from left to right or vice versa it will move the entire window and show grey behind it. It will be great to find out how pages stop that from happening.

Thanks guys and I appreciate it, once again this is hard to find on the tinterwebs and should come in handy for others who want to do the same. :D

//Giles